# Object Detection OpenCV-Python does not work

Tags: python, opencv

For several days I am have been trying to build my own object classification program using Python-Open cv and Haar Cascade.

After creating the samples, here is how train the system:

```
 opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt -numStages 12 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000 -numNeg 600 -w 50 -h 50 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024
```

and after stage 8 I have received this output

```
===== TRAINING 8-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   1000 : 1000
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    600 : 0.00221078
Precalculation time: 10
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|    0.898333|                                                      
+----+---------+---------+
|   4|        1| 0.916667|
+----+---------+---------+
|   5|        1| 0.691667|
+----+---------+---------+
|   6|        1| 0.681667|
+----+---------+---------+
|   7|        1| 0.518333|
+----+---------+---------+
|   8|        1| 0.626667|
+----+---------+---------+
|   9|        1| 0.441667|
+----+---------+---------+

===== TRAINING 9-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   1000 : 1000
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    0 : 0
Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.
```

However the trained model does not detect any object (watch in this case). I am stucked and don't know how to solve this out. Any useful ideas are appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired parameters were acheived: "-minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5".

You have (according the table you show above): HitRate=1 and FalseAlarmRate=0.441667, that's why training stopped.

Comment: ok, this answers why training stopped, thanks. But why the trained system doesn't detect anything? Can it imply the training was not successful for example as result of overfitting? In what way I can improve my training in your view?

Comment: It another large question. You need to set correct parameters for your objects, and these parameters strongly depends on object you detect. You can check HR and FA for verification set, and it will show if it overfitting. If it so, you need increase training set (in some cases it helps, but not mandatory, as I said it strongly depends on your datasets).

Comment: Thanks. "You can check HR and FA for verification set, and it will show if it overfitting"  , this is quite interesting, how can I do that?

Comment: HR=N_true_positives/(total_number_of _samples) , FA=N_false_positives/(total_number_of_samples).

Comment: And this question is more suitable for CrossValidated forum http://stats.stackexchange.com/